# Android Firebase Filter by user id

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have made simple "post blog" app where user can post particular post.
All the posts are showed in `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`, and they work just fine.
However I want to filter the posts so its shows only the current user posts.

I have defined query to filter by user id, but for some reason it does not work as it still shows the post of all users.

```
userAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mCurrentUser = userAuth.getCurrentUser();
    AuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
                Intent loginIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LogInActivity.class);
                loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(loginIntent);
            }
        }
    };

    
    myDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("HelpPosts");
    DatabaseOfUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

    //make a filter for post
    userId = userAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    CurrentUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("HelpPosts");
    mQueryCurrentUser = CurrentUser.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(userId);

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    userAuth.addAuthStateListener(AuthListener);

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post,PostViewHolder>firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder>
            (Post.class,
             R.layout.post_row,
             PostViewHolder.class,
             CurrentUser) {


        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(PostViewHolder viewHolder, Post model, final int position) {
            final String post_key = getRef(position).getKey();
            viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
            viewHolder.setDesc(model.getDesc());
            viewHolder.setTnumber(model.getPhone());
            viewHolder.setUsername(model.getUsername());

            viewHolder.myView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent singleView = new Intent(MainActivity.this,PostView.class);
                    singleView.putExtra("post_id",post_key);
                    startActivity(singleView);
                }
            });
        }
    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}
```

Firebase data

```
"HelpPosts" : {
"-Kg9elNpSVKA1EY6Fh6X" : {
  "Address" : "test",
  "Desc" : "test",
  "Phone" : "5555",
  "Title" : "test1",
  "uid" : "FuOOyBOVtDaqrY4mgpquH935HSV2",
  "username" : "marius"
},
"-Kg9euxfW9ivRq80NwV3" : {
  "Address" : "test",
  "Desc" : "test",
  "Phone" : "2222",
  "Title" : "test2",
  "uid" : "FuOOyBOVtDaqrY4mgpquH935HSV2",
  "username" : "marius"
},
"-Kg9fIrq-hmUucb_R1b7" : {
  "Address" : "test",
  "Desc" : "test",
  "Phone" : "2222",
  "Title" : "test3",
  "uid" : "MgADOIrKbPQGo7pkfJzzCJAMwOk1",
  "username" : "mario"
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Great code you have there. And you only miss one tiny step: on your `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` initialization, you should use `mQueryCurrentUser` instead of `CurrentUser`. Like this:

```
 FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post,PostViewHolder>firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder>
        (Post.class,
         R.layout.post_row,
         PostViewHolder.class,
         mQueryCurrentUser) {
 ...
```

And that should do it

Answer (score -2):

```
userId = userAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
CurrentUser =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("HelpPosts");
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post,PostViewHolder>firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder>
(Post.class,
        R.layout.post_row,
        PostViewHolder.class 
        CurrentUser.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(userId))
```